# Shortcodes unavailable with Divi

Tags: wordpress

I use the DIVI template to build my pages and integrate CiviCRM.
I don't see the "Civi Shorthcodes" button neither with Divi nor with Gutenberg.

How can I access the shortcodes?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Divi but with Guttenberg you can use either the shortcode block or paragraph block.

Just paste the code in there e.g. [civicrm component="event" action="info" id="1"]